# Pyrogram: использование в filters списка

Tags: pyrogram

Нужно сделать, чтобы телеграм бот парсил информацию с разных телеграм каналов. Для этого я хочу использовать списки.
Как это реализовать? Сделайте скидку на новичка, не пинайте в документацию- я еще только на пути к ее изучению. И берёт, почему-то только второй источник

donors_ids = [-1002013306534, -1001965389659]

```
user_bot.add_handler(MessageHandler(new_post, filters.chat(chats=donors_id)
```

Comment: чтобы использовать списки, надо уметь делать с ними хотя бы элементарные вещи. А тут это знание отсутствует. Поэтому сначала учебник, а потом уже делать телеграм-боты.

Comment: Тут дело скорей, в мотивации. Не учу питон, поэтому решила сделать бота, а наоборот- нужен бот, поэтому села за питон. А вообще, спасибо за совет, правда, пользы он никакой не несет.

Answer (score 0):

Если ты используешь библиотеку python-telegram-bot, то решение можно найти с использованием списков:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters

# Создаем экземпляр Updater и передаем токен бота
updater = Updater(token='YOUR_BOT_TOKEN', use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

# Список с ID каналов, которые ты хочешь парсить
donors_ids = [-1002013306534, -1001965389659]

# Функция, которая будет вызываться при получении нового поста
def new_post(update, context):
    # Твой код обработки поста
    pass

# Создаем хэндлер с фильтром по списку ID каналов
donors_filter = Filters.chat(chat_id=donors_ids)
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(donors_filter, new_post))

# Запускаем бота
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! Я использую pyrogram, их можно использовать вместе?

Comment: Да, в теории, можно использовать Pyrogram вместе с python-telegram-bot, но в практике это может быть несколько сложно из-за того, что обе библиотеки предоставляют собственные способы взаимодействия с API Telegram и могут работать в асинхронном режиме.